# Implicit vs implicit val in Scala case classes

Tags: scala, implicit

I want to understand the difference between `implicit` and `implicit val` in Scala case class parameters, especially when inheritance is involved. I have the following code:

```
abstract class T(implicit x: Int)
case class T1(a: Int)(implicit x: Int) extends T
```

This one compiles just fine. However, when I create an object of type `T1`, I do not have access to the field `x`. After some digging around, it looks like I need to use `implicit val x` in `T1` definition instead:

```
abstract class T(implicit x: Int)
case class T1(a: Int)(implicit val x: Int) extends T
```

This allows me to access `t.x` for `t` of type `T1`. Then, I wonder if I should also use `implicit val x` in `T` as well. It turns out the following code produces a compile error:

```
abstract class T(implicit val x: Int)
case class T1(a: Int)(implicit val x: Int) extends T
```

Specifically the compiler wants be to use the `override` keyword.

How are `implicit` vs `implicit val` different exactly? Why do they affect whether `x` is visible as a field? What do they have to do with whether I need the `override` keyword?

Comment: This is really the difference between `class T(x: Int)` vs a `class T(val x: Int)`. In the first case, the `x` is just parameter to the constructor of the class `T`, while in the second case it is also a public field of the class. As such, if you want your second class to also have an `x` then it must override it.Or, you can mark as public only one of them. - However, it seems weird to me to have a public implicit, usually the idea of implicits is to use them, well, implicitly. Thus, it seems weird that you wanted to access it explicitly.

Comment: It seems that case class normally makes constructor parameters public by default. For example, I can access `t.a` (for `t: T1`) without saying `val a: Int`. Is it simply part of the spec that this does not apply if the parameter is `implicit`?

Comment: Yes, for **Case Classes** the constructor parameters of their first arguments group are made public by default. But for the second group _(or in general, for the other groups)_ they do not, no matter if they are implicit or not. But, again, why do you want to access it? Maybe this is an **XY Problem**.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm representing an AST of a language. Each case class is a language construct. The implicit is a reference to the raw parse tree, which contains the location in the file, the raw text, etc., that's helpful for producing an error message. I since decided to avoid accessing the implicit as a public field and instead added methods to the class to extract what I actually need (e.g., the source location). I wonder if that's a good idea.

It might be an XY problem, although with me being new to Scala both the X and the Y are interesting to me!